# How can I stop/pause the buffering of a video with Popcorn.js?

Tags: javascript, video, streaming

Basically I want to pause or stop the buffering of a video when triggering an event. Ex: stop/resume the buffering when clicking the video.

I know there is a [preload](http://popcornjs.org/popcorn-docs/media-methods/#preload) function for buffering the video, so I'm looking for the complete opposite.